# ASP.NET Comet Approach vs WCF Callback

Tags: asp.net, comet, wcf-callbacks

I want / have to implement a chat (like facebooks) in my web app. Through my research I've found two different approaches and I don't know which want I should take (to be honest I tried one but it has a strange behavior, but let me come to this later).

Some facts about my application. It has two different clients. One is a web-application, the other one is a wpf client. Both of these two clients should have implemented a chat. They communicate over a server via WCF-Services.

So, as I found out there is the comet approach which means AJAX Long Polling. On the other hand I can use WCF Callback Services.

Are there any dis/advantages  of the WCF callback / Comet approach?

For me the callback approach is pretty straight forward, ajax long pooling sound much more complicated.

Thx's in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would offer you to try Reverse Ajax over [PokeIn](http://pokein.com) and benefit from the built-in [WebSocket](http://www.pokein.com/Help/WebSocketFeature.aspx) feature. You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking at MS technology you'll probably be interested in reading this post by Brian Raymor who is a Senior Program Manager in the Windows Networking group at Microsoft.

- [WebSockets: Stable and Ready for Developers](http://www.sitepoint.com/websockets-stable-and-ready-for-developers/)

[SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) is a good solution since it will choose a transport type suitable for the web browser that is making a connection. It won't work with IIS until Windows Server 8.

Your other options are [XSockets](http://xsockets.net), [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) and more. See this [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) (disclaimer: which I maintain)

You could also look at a hosted service. Again, there are options available in the guide I've provided a link to above.

Answer (score -1):

I would check out SignalR for the Web application side at least http://geekswithblogs.net/jeroenb/archive/2011/12/14/signalr-starter-application.aspx